# DS-160 B1/B2 US visa question for a short visit of prospective PhD student

Tags: visas, usa

*Preamble*: I do not hold US visa currently and have never been to the US. I am a citizen from Eastern Europe (non-EU) and I this summer I am finishing my studies at local university. Recently, I have been admitted to PhD programs in several top US universities (yay!). Now I am facing a hard choice of selecting a place to do my PhD. I contacted professors basically everywhere and was strongly advised to visit the universities on the Open House days (option to visit on other days is also present) to get the feeling of the place.

The perfect option for me would be to plan, for example, a week trip, when I would stay for day or two at each campus and communicate with people. I am also offered financial assistance by the universities (different universities have different terms, e.g. one reimburses aviatickets and accommodation; other provide me with a fixed, but sufficient, sum of money for two days). Seems feasible, doesn't it?

*Additional information about my status and finances*: I am married, studying and have a stable (but very moderate) income from a job in laboratory at my university. I have not much savings. Perhaps, I would need to contact universities personally concerning this, asking them to speed up reimbursement, if possible, in order to to facilitate my visit. I definitely have money for tickets and some spare money for the stay (food, public transport), but perhaps I don't have enough for full cover of accommodation (but, in fact, I don't need it as I will be provided by it).

**The question is:** what should I put in the form "Payer"? The travel is funded by myself in combination with several institution providing aid for my short stays. In the form I should either check "self-paid" or enter information about *only one* organization.

It would be helpful if someone had any information on this or useful links. Thank you!

Comment: You’re agonizing over nothing all. The USA interviews visa applicants and you can provide details about your financing at the interview. Choose **self paid** and one other institution. You will have the opportunity to clarify at your interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USA interviews all new visitor visa applicants and you can provide details about your financing at the interview.

Choose **self paid** and one other institution. You will have the opportunity to clarify at your interview.

Comment: Thank you for your input! As I stated in the question, I should either check "self-paid" OR enter information about only one organization. I cannot check both "self-paid" AND one other institution. And choosing either would be not true, as I cannot cover the whole trip myself, as well as institutions only cover parts of my trip. This is my concern.

Comment: @Gretchen Choose the institution if you will have a letter of funding from them before your interview. Visa forms are not perfect to address every situation, they design them to be pragmatic. Like I wrote, you will have an interview so this is nothing to worry about. I've applied for enough US visas successfully to know how it works.